# What is the probability each team wins the tournament?

Tags: probability

> $A, B, C, D$ are four teams in a tournament where $A$ faces $B$ and $C$ faces $D$ in the first round and the winners of those rounds face each other.  $A$ has a $0.7$ probability of beating any other team, while $B, C, D$ have a $0.5$ probability of beating each other.  If the games are independent, what is the probability that each team wins the tournament?

My idea is $P(\text{$A$ wins})=P[A \text{ beats } B $ and  ($A \text{ beats } C$ or $A \text{ beats D}$)$]$  $=P[(A \text{ beats B and A beats C) or (A beats B and A beats D)}]$ $=0.7*0.7 + 0.7*0.7 =98$%, and repeating this process for each $B,C,D$ but this seems incorrect.

Is there an easier way to go about this?

Comment: $A$ wins with probability $0.7\cdot 0.5=0.35$.  How you got $0.98$ I have no idea.  Similarly, $B$ will win by first beating $A$ and then beating whichever of the remaining opponents are left, which occurs with probability...   Finally, we can get the probability for $C$ and $D$ by appealing to symmetry and that it must be half of the remaining available probability.

Comment: @JMoravitz He said $A$ wins with probability $0.7$ against _all_ teams. Should it not be $0.49$?

Comment: @JMoravitz I edited my question to show specifically how I got $0.98$, what have I incorrectly assumed to get that number?

Comment: @bames sure would, good catch.  And now that he has edited, we can see where his mistake lies.  When $A$ beats $B$, he moves on to play against the other remaining player, but *this is conditioned on that player having won his own game*!.  If you insist on keeping track of who the second opponent is for $A$, then you need a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in front of each.  Note, it doesn't make sense for the probability that $A$ wins the tournament as a whole to be higher than the probability that $A$ wins his first game.

Comment: So assuming $P(A \text{ wins })=0.7 * 0.7 = 0.49$, $P(B) = 0.3 * 0.5 = 0.15$, $P(C) = 0.5 * 0.5=0.25$ and $P(D)= 0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25$ then we have the probability of the sample space is greater than $1$.  What mistake did I make here?

Comment: @OliverG See my answer.

Comment: $P(C)\neq 0.5\cdot 0.5$.  $C$'s chances of winning the first game are indeed $0.5$, but the chance that $C$ wins the second game depends on whether he is playing against $A$ or playing against $B$.  In the case he is playing against $A$ he has a worse chance of winning than usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $A$ has probability $0.7$ of beating all teams, it doesn't matter who wins in the $C$ vs. $D$ match. We have
$$P(A\text{ wins})= P(A\text{ wins twice})=0.7\cdot0.7=0.49$$
Similarly, since $B$ has probability $0.5$ of beating both $C$ and $D$, we can write:
$$P(B\text{ wins}) = P(B\text{ beats }A)P(B\text{ wins next game}) = 0.3 \cdot 0.5 = 0.15$$
By symmetry, the probability that $C$ wins is the same as the probability that $D$ wins. We have:
\begin{align}
P(C\text{ wins}) &= P(C\text{ beats }D)\left[P(A\text{ beats }B)P(C\text{ beats }A) + P(B\text{ beats }A)P(C\text{ beats }B)\right]\\
&=0.5(0.7\cdot0.3+0.3\cdot0.5) \\
&=0.5\cdot 0.36 \\
&= 0.18\\
&=P(D\text{ wins})
\end{align}
An easier way to get $P(C\text{ wins})$ is to divide the remaining probability $1 - (0.49 + 0.15) = 0.36$ by $2$, since $C$ and $D$ have the same chance of winning the tournament.

Comment: What is the sample space you're using here?  I don't understand what you mean by "$A$ wins twice".  I was assuming the sample space had two ways to win for each team as in $A$ wins by beating $B$ and $C$ or $A$ wins by beating $B$ and $D$.

Comment: @OliverG $A$ wins the first game with probability $0.7$, and $A$ wins the second game with probability $0.7$ as well, regardless of whether $C$ won or $D$ won in the $C$ vs $D$ game because $A$ wins with probability $0.7$ against everyone. "$A$ wins twice" means that $A$ wins in both the first and second round of the tournament.

Comment: Can you explain what sample space you chose?  What's incorrect about using the sample space I chose?

Comment: @OliverG It is the same sample space as yours. You simply calculated the probabilities incorrectly, as JMoravitz pointed out. The probability that $C$ wins the second game is not $0.5$, since the probability of $C$ winning against $A$ ($0.3$) is different from the probability that $C$ wins against $B$ ($0.5$)...

Comment: @OliverG nothing is wrong with the samplespace either person chose, but you are ignoring the chance that $A$ gets the chance to play against $C$ in the first place in your calculations.  If you want, you could write it like barnes did, but it gets tedious to parse: $A$ wins tournament $=$($A$ beats $B$ in rd1) and ((($A$ beats $C$ in rd2) and ($C$ beats $D$ in rd1)) or (($A$ beats $D$ in rd2) and ($D$ beats $C$ in rd1))), yielding the calculation $0.7\cdot((0.7\cdot 0.5)+(0.7\cdot 0.5))=0.49$

Comment: I think I understand now, the sample space I was using was incorrect.  Does it make sense to say the sample space elements are like $(A,C,A)$ where this means $A$ wins first round, $C$ wins first round, then $A$ wins the last round?  Then $P(A \text{ wins }) = P((A,C,A) \cup (A, D, A)) = P(A)P(C)P(A) + P(A)P(D)P(A)$?

Comment: @OliverG Yes, that seems to work!